# Ps3 tutorial "Add the following line to your CMakeLists.txt file" where?

Tags: ros, joy-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going through the PS3 tutorials hoping to learn how to control a quadrotor using ros with a controler. In the tutorial Writing a Teleoperation Node for the PS3 Joystick you are told to  add to the CMakeList.text file
rosbuild_add_executable(turtle_teleop_ps3joy src/turtle_teleop_ps3joy.cpp)
and then run rosbuild on your file.
I'm not sure how to do this? In which CMakeList do I add this? In the src file in my workspace? Or in the package I'm working in? And were in the CMakeList do I add it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188018/ps3-tutorial-%22add-the-following-line-to-your-cmakelists.txt-file%22-where?/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1)The CMakeLists.txt that you need to modify is the one inside the folder of the package you've created for the tutorial.

2)You can add the additional line at the bottom of the document.

3)After you save the file, you need to run rosmake on your package. Open a new terminal and type:

`rosmake learning_ps3joy`

If you used a different name for the package, remember to change it in the above command as well.

I'm new to ROS, so I may have said something wrong or missed some step.

Hope this helps you.

---

Originally posted by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) with karma: 53 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on 2014-07-29**:
Hi, so I tried this and am now getting an error

[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['learning_ps3joy/']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

I'm not sure if this is the same issue or a new one? Thanks

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-07-30**:
Try following the instructions I posted in your other question

**Comment by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on 2014-07-30**:
Thanks. That worked, but now I'm having new problems... I'll post a new question if I can't figure this out.